# How to measure sizes and distances from parts of an image file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, software-recommendation, image-sprite

I have this image sprite containing many small icons.

I don't know the accurate size, height and width of each icon and it's too difficult for me to find it manually with my current tools (I am using Google chrome to edit CSS). Additionally, I need to know, in pixels, how far each icon is from the top and left of the whole image file.

This is the image file:

[image: icons]

Are there any software or Photoshop tools that will enable me to select each icon and find out how big it is, and how far it is from the top and left of the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use rulers in photoshop and the marquee tool to find out. Set the grid in the preferences to 1px and snap to it.

You'll be able to measure stuff out from there.  Maybe try taking the white space out to make your background-position offsets easier to calculate.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, these images are spaced apart evenly. You could probably just do the math. Total width / 5 by total height / 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpecKing plugin to measure distances and sizes and texts properties:
[http://www.wuwacorp.com/](http://www.wuwacorp.com)